# Raise Property Changed event very slow

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, mvvm-light, winrt-xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I am working on a Windows RT/Windows Store App and when performing a `RaisePropertyChanged("...")` call in my code (using the MVVM-light framework, this should be very similar to the standard `OnPropertyChanged` if I was to directly implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface - in fact I tested both) it is very slow.

Delays before the UI updates occur do vary; I raise a property changed event to disable a button and three text boxes, however to do this update on the UI it typically takes between 1.5-2 seconds. Quite frustrating. Why is this not instant? My `.xaml` view is not very complex.

On my button `Command`:

```
        SubmitCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(RunSubmitCommand);
        ...
        private async void RunSubmitCommand(string param)
        {
            submitted = true;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CanSubmit);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CanEnterValues);
        }
```

Properties look like this:

```
        public bool CanSubmit
        {
            // formatted for readability on SO
            // IsField1Valid, IsField2Valid, IsField3Valid I should mention 
            // just resolve nullable bool's
            get { return !submitted && 
                         IsField1Valid.GetValueOrDefault() && 
                         IsField2Valid.GetValueOrDefault() && 
                         IsField3Valid.GetValueOrDefault(); }
        }

        public bool CanEnterValues
        {
            get { return !submitted; }
        }
```

Text fields and submit button look like this on `.xaml`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextField1Box" TabIndex="1" Text="{Binding Field1}" 
  IsEnabled="{Binding CanEnterValues}" Style="{StaticResource ValueTextBoxStyle}"
  LostFocus="Field1TextBox_LostFocus" />
... x 2 more

<Button x:Name="SubmitButton" TabIndex="4" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
  Content="Submit Values" IsEnabled="{Binding CanSubmit}" 
  Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
```

Any ideas on the delay would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a small repro project to test it? It should be instant.

Comment: Yes I might try this, I do have a countdown <TextBlock /> which is counting down from 60 seconds, I wonder if the update could be getting queued or something? :\

Comment: Perhaps it somehow blocks the UI thread for a second when it waits. Or some animation causes an implicit change of CacheMode to BitmapCache and that prevents the change from showing up.

Comment: Sorry been really busy, will try and do this tomorrow night.